# How to perform unary operations on a class in Python?

Tags: python, class, fractions, unary-operator

I have written a code where I have defined a class `Fraction`. Throughout the code, all binary operations such as `+, -, /, *` can be performed. Now I would also like to be able to perform unary operations for the class `Fraction` such as `abs()` etc. However, this does not work at the moment, when performing for example the unary operation `abs()` I get a `TypeError`: bad operand type for abs (): 'Fraction'. Below is part of the code that deals purely with fraction subtraction, it is representative for the entire code:

```
def gcd(denominator, numerator):
    if numerator == 0:
        return denominator
    else:
        return gcd(numerator, (denominator % numerator))

class Fraction:
    
    def __init__(self,numerator = 0, denominator = 1):

        self.numerator = int(numerator / gcd(abs(denominator),abs(numerator) ))
        self.denominator = int(denominator / gcd(abs(denominator),abs(numerator) ))
        if self.denominator < 0:
            self.denominator = abs(self.denominator)
            self.numerator = -1*self.numerator
        elif self.denominator == 0:
            raise ZeroDivisionError
        
    def __str__(self):
        if self.denominator == 1:
            return str(self.numerator)
        else:
            return str(self.numerator) + "/" + str(self.denominator)
    
    def __neg__(self):
        return Fraction(-self.numerator, self.denominator)
    
    def __rsub__(self,other):
        return self.__sub__(other)

    def __sub__(self,other):
        if type(other) == int:
            other = Fraction(other,1)
            return self.sub(other)
        else:
            
            return self.sub(other)
    
    def sub(self,other):
        result = Fraction()
        
        result.numerator = other.denominator * self.numerator - self.denominator * other.numerator
        result.denominator = other.denominator * self.denominator
        
        multiple = gcd(result.denominator,result.numerator)
        
        result.numerator = int(result.numerator / multiple)
        result.denominator = int(result.denominator / multiple)
        
        if result.denominator < 0:
            result.denominator = abs(result.denominator)
            result.numerator = 0 - result.numerator
            return result    
        
        else:
            return result
        
        return result


p = Fraction(2,3)
q = Fraction(4,5)

r = (p - q)
```

What I would like is that when I give the statement `print(abs(r))` the output is the fraction in absolute value. So in the example where *p = Fraction(2,3)*, *q = Fraction(4,5)* and *r = (p - q)*. Then the statement `print(r)` gives the output *-2/15* and the statement `print(abs(r))` gives the output *2/15*. Or that for example `print(float(r))` gives the output *-0.133333333*. However, I keep getting the previously mentioned `TypeError`.

I've been looking for a while, but so far I haven't been able to find a solution, do you know how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to implement [`def __abs__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__abs__)

Comment: For a more general reference, I recommend [this article](https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/) for a list of all of Python's `__dunder__` magic methods.

Comment: @SvenEberth Thanks for your quick response! Could you maybe explain how to implement it. I am quite new to python and completely new to classes.

Comment: `def __abs__(self): return value_of_abs_of_self`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comment implement [`__abs__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__abs__) and `__float__`.

Add this to your class:

```
    def __abs__(self):
        return Fraction(abs(self.numerator), abs(self.denominator))

    def __float__(self):
        return self.numerator / self.denominator
```

Maybe

```
    def __abs__(self):
        return Fraction(abs(self.numerator), self.denominator)
```

would be already enough, when your denominator is always positive.

```
>>> p = Fraction(2, 3)
>>> q = Fraction(4, 5)
>>> r = p - q
>>> print(r)
-2/15
>>> print(abs(r))
2/15
>>> print(float(r))
-0.13333333333333333
```

Comment: Yep, absolutely great. I actually got it working! Can this also be done in the same way for `print(float(r))` ?